# Calculate time difference between two consecutive rows, show only results greater than

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
RecordID     user_id                transaction_date
1            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:31:24
2            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:38:55
3            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:44:39
4            USER1                  27-05-2021 19:00:42
5            USER1                  27-05-2021 19:06:23


SELECT user_id, TO_CHAR(dstamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS transaction_time
FROM inventory_transaction
WHERE dstamp BETWEEN to_date('27/05/2021 18:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  AND            
                 to_date('28/05/2021 06:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
ORDER BY user_id;
```

I need this output:

```
RecordID     user_id                transaction_date            DIFFERENCE
1            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:31:24         (null)
2            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:38:55         00:07:31
3            USER1                  27-05-2021 18:44:39         00:05:44
4            USER1                  27-05-2021 19:00:42         00:16:03
5            USER1                  27-05-2021 19:06:23         00:05:41
```

I need to get the difference between consecutive transaction date values. I am using oracle sql dev 12.
Any ideas?
Thank You very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
SELECT user_id, TO_CHAR(dstamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS transaction_time,
       (dstamp - prev_stamp) * (24 * 60 * 60) as diff_seconds
FROM (SELECT it.*,
             LAG(dstamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY dstamp) as prev_dstamp
      FROM inventory_transaction it
     ) it
WHERE dstamp BETWEEN to_date('27/05/2021 18:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  AND            
                 to_date('28/05/2021 06:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
ORDER BY user_id;
```

In Oracle it is easier to get the difference as seconds rather than in a time format.